# Dockers ans scalability

Tags: java, docker

I have several questions about dockers for freshers, could somebody help me please?

1. **As I learned**, containers don't have OS inside of them, they all share one OS of the cloud server.
   But what if I want to deploy app that was written from diff platform?
   For example I have Linux on server, but on my own machine I've Windows.
   So I develop java app, using JDK for windows..
   Now I use docker to build the image (as I understand I should pack my app, its libs and JDK for windows at one container with help of docker file and put it to Linux Server...so how my app will work on Linux inside of container?)
   Please help me to understand how does it work, becouse I miss something here
2. **Scalability**. Why we want to copy the applications on server (as written, the containers are very lightweight and easy to copy), why not to use multithreading?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: "No OS" is misleading. It's more correct to think "No Kernel and just enough of the rest of the OS to work". I.e. a "full OS" usually contains a kernel, some libraries, some daemons, maybe a UI system such as X11. Inside a docker container you remove the kernel (as that's provided by the host) and **most** libraries and usually **all** daemons so that only the *specific* parts needed by the app running there are present.

Answer (score 1):

0. Containers do have OS's - for example you can run AlpineOS or Fedora containers on Ubuntu. The package space and libraries are not shared with the host.
1. Java doesn't care where you run it; Docker is not a requirement. In any case, you can package the app with a Windows JDK (no container) and copy it into a container with only a JRE (you should only need a JDK to compile). Or you use multi-stage Docker builds to use a Linux JDK to compile and package your artifacts, then copy that into the same JRE runtime layer
2. Containers and multithreading aren't exclusive. Besides, I think you meant multi-processing which would require an external supervisor process (which is specific to the OS), compared to using a container orchestrator. Also copies of the application artifact shouldn't be needed, only memory space needed for the process(es)